# How do I make a file into a UTF 8 in the first place?

Tags: utf-8, text-mining, quanteda

I have recently embarked on a text mining journey; I have no experience and I am only trying to learn the basics. Though I have found online tutorials on how to use and load files in **Quanteda** for example, nowhere is addressed the most critical (for me) issue: How to make a file in UTF-8 format in the first place.

For example, I am trying to use the **Quanteda** package in R. I downloaded some texts from the Project Gutemberg, a database where all documents can be also downloaded as plain text files in UTF-8 form. So far so good. As you can see below on my code, everything has worked perfectly fine.

Here comes the serious question: As a researcher I am interested to mine some studies (for academic reasons). I will usually find my studies in PubMed, NCBI, Scopus, etc. These databases allow some of their studies to be downloaded into PDF formats and they usually contain graphs or tables or images and so on. Therefore, it is obvious that the situation is not as simple as it is shown in many tutorials as I would never be interested to mine a Harry Potter book for academic reasons.

How do it then? As you can see in my code, the two texts have been successfully loaded into a dataframe and turned into a corpus but where to start from when one deals with a simple PDF case? Could it be the case that I just have to manually copy the whole text from a study, paste it on a document and turn it into a .txt format? I don't think so.

Any suggestion welcomed :)
[loading the texts into a dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhwX1.png)
[making the corpus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lovYZ.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: UTF-8 is one of the many encoding available. Modern documents use it. Else you should check the encoding information in the file (or in protocol). HTTP gives you an encoding. HTML may indicate also the encoding. Else you should guess it. Which languages? English? Use UTF-8 and as fallback Latin1. DO you need to decode all symbols, or just letters? For other languages: check which encoding were used (DOS, WIndows, Old Mac, etc.) PDF: assume UTF-8 or latin 1 (it depends on the font used, but most "untext" program will convert to you.